# RSA Archer - Multiple application layouts and their use

Tags: archer, rsa-archer-grc

I have found the possibility to define multiple Layouts for an Archer application but I didn't understand how to use them.  For example when I add a record I see the default layout and the promo I created. How can I point to some other Layouts and on what occasions? How can I switch from one Layout to another and when does this make sense?
Thank you in advance for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Giovanni, multiple layouts in Archer are used in conjunction with Advanced Workflow.  Once Advanced Workflow is enabled you can add as many layout as you want.  In order to change the layout you need to design a workflow from Start to End.

Archer's online help will give you some guidance and also here are some useful documentation (may require a valid login to see):

- https://community.rsa.com/docs/DOC-98855
- https://community.rsa.com/docs/DOC-98390
- https://community.rsa.com/docs/DOC-98988
- https://community.rsa.com/docs/DOC-98227